# How to implement a snapshot system in Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, implementation, snapshot

as I mentioned I want to implement a backup/snapshot feature for my web app.

As for details, imagine each User has several Projects which has several Components which also has several Subcomponents. Those are the entities that I want to backup apart from User.

The goal that I want to achieve is that user may save the current state as a snapshot and later if he doesn't like the new configuration, can easily turn back to his save and there can be multiple snapshots. Those snapshots has to be read only.

I'm asking for a design architecture or style or any kind of idea to implement. That's why I didn't put my entities here.

Thanks, beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

I have some similar versioning in a project where I manage that in a service by simply introduced another entity. In your case that would be a `ProjectVersion` and the `Project` has a list (OneToMany) of these versions and additionally a ManyToOne (or OneToOne) relation to one `ProjectVersion` called `master`. The `Project` itself has no more fields.

A few days ago I stumbled across @Version from java persistence API (not the spring one) and this annotation should help to automatically increase and manage a version value in the entity during updates. But I haven’t tested it myself.

Comment: Could you please expand the idea more, sir? Or perhaps a link to that @Version annotation documentation. Thanks in advance

Comment: I read about here: http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa and this is the official docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Version.html